# How can we post more questions on Ask Ubuntu without the 40 minute rule?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I get several questions but here I can only one question in 40 minutes. If I am posting more than one question in single question, I am getting objected by users. How to solve this so I can post more questions especially very relevant to Ubuntu? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This site has a protection against users that post rubbish. Spam.  That 40 minute rule is one of the hurdles in place to prevent that. And yes I have seen what happens without that rule. It is unfortunately needed to keep the frontpage useable.

AU wants you to 1st proof you are serious and you do that by answering a few questions. You gain reputation rather quickly for answering questions with a well written response.

And when you have reputation all those hurdles disappear.

125 is the magic number for this specific hurdle. I can guarantee you 125 rep in minutes: questions where you can answer by copying parts from the man page tend to get 10 upvotes and an accept.

See https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges for a list on privileges.

Comment: *Solution to get rid of this:* Earn 125 points :)

Comment: Great! Thanks. I will try earn those points. :) Actually I am a new user. I am serious but I need more knowledge to answer others' questions. I will try get the points soon. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hi!! I succeeded in getting 125 points inside Ask Ubuntu (I now have 129 points in Ask Ubuntu) and now I am getting following message when I am trying to post a new question: https://i.imgur.com/nlzoxK8.png

Comment: @MaverickInnocent I think it's amazing that you want to contribute a lot to Ask Ubuntu, but is the 6 questions a day really such a hurdle? I think even the 40 minutes cool-off period might be helpful for us to get clearer about what's the problem we're facing. Like Rinzwind said, unfortunately these limits are very important for fending off spam, bots, bad questions etc.

Comment: @MaverickInnocent here is a list https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Comment: @flen. Thank you friend. Actually, I am a new user who is eager to get acclimatised to Ubuntu the fastest. So this rule may only be limiting now, later it may not be a hurdle. You are right about spam and I also understand rules (cannot be / should not be) relaxed for one particular individual, so I am following a new method of typing questions down in notepad and posting only when I am allowed.

Comment: @Rinzwind, thank you! It did not indicate at how many credits, the 24 hour time limit will go but link is useful nevertheless. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: As a feedback, it would be better if one can see at least how much time is left before one can post again. Thanks :)

Comment: That would mean spammers could put a timer on their script.

Comment: Oh. ok. But a spammer could be banned directly by moderators right? This seems more difficult than it looks to maintain a website. Anyways thank you. :)